# Flask: Array Response of Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask

I'm trying to iterate the array in order to create span elements inside a Div

**js**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('form').submit(function (e) {
            var url = "{{ url_for('ajaxPP') }}"; // send the form data here.
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $('form').serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
                dataType:'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#result').html("<br>"+data.result);
                    $('input[name="search-input"]').val("");
                    $('input[name="search-input"]').focus();
                    console.log(data)  // display the returned data in the console.
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault(); // block the traditional submission of the form.
        });
      });
</script>
```

Trying to access *using: data.result[0], data[0], result[0]*, it's not working

**console response**

```
{result: Array(1)}result: Array(1)0: Array(6)0: "Test1"1: "Test2"2: "Test3"3: 118804: "Test5"5: nulllength: 6__proto__: Array(0)length: 1__proto__: Array(0)__proto__: Object
```

**app.py**

```
@app.route('/ajaxPP',methods=['POST'])
def ajaxPP():
  if request.method == 'POST':
    us = request.form['search-input']
    user = getUser(us)
    return jsonify(result=user)
```

Comment: can you add stringify data in your question console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) like this

Comment: Actually, I wanna iterate the array, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got iterate the array using:

```
$('#result').html("<br>"+data.result[0][0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The data coming back from your server is not properly formed JSON. You'll want to wrap your response in Flask's 'jsonify' method.

Comment: I updated my questions, but my response in a jsonify method